# How to get last textarea of an div and set focus on that by javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript

I have a div with many textarea and text fields tag I want to find last textarea/text field tag whichever last in the div and need to set focus on that by JavaScript

HTML wil be like this

```
 <div id="mylistId">
    <div><p><input type="text"/></p></div>
    <div><p><textarea rows="2"  cols="100"/></p></div>
    <div><p><input type="text"/></p></div>
    <div></p><textarea rows="2"  cols="100"/></p></div>
    <div></p><textarea rows="2"  cols="100"/></p></div>
    <div></p><textarea rows="2"  cols="100"/></p></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: How about finding the last textarea and setting focus on it?

Comment: `document.querySelector('div textarea:last-of-type').focus()`

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'),-1)[0].focus()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to get all textarea inside div after focus last one using **[`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)**

```js
var ele = document.querySelectorAll('#mylistId textarea');
ele[ele.length - 1].focus();
```

```html
<div id="mylistId">
  <div>
    <p>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <textarea rows="2" cols="100"></textarea>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <textarea rows="2" cols="100"></textarea>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <textarea rows="2" cols="100"></textarea>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <textarea rows="2" cols="100"></textarea>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var div = document.getElementById("YourDivID");
var nodes = div.querySelectorAll('textarea');
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1]; //Last Textarea
    last.focus();
```

**[See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck79nqgo/1/)**

Comment: He wants to set the focus too, who knows, maybe that's where he was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

With ES5 you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)/[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in a similar way.

```
var textarea = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).pop();
```

That is, get all the `textarea`s, convert the node list to `array` (using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)) and [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) the last element.

Then you [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus):

```
textarea.focus();
```

#### Option 2

IF you are sure all your `textarea`s are inside the same `div` you can use `last-child` pseudo class:

```
var textarea = document.querySelector("div textarea:last-child");
textarea.focus();
```

One liner:

```
document.querySelector("div textarea:last-child").focus();
```

#### Edit

Based on your html snippet the **option 1** will fit best.

Answer (score -1):

You can give them a common class and then use the class to select them like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('className').lastChild.focus();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agreed with @torazaburo NodeList has no lastChild attribute.